# Произведение без умножения, как можно улучшить код?

Tags: java

Добрый день. 
Выполнял задачу на http://informatics.msk.ru/ под номером 112202. 
Задача:

> Напишите программу, которая вводит два целых числа и находит их 
>   произведение, не используя операцию умножения. Учтите, что числа могут 
>   быть отрицательными.

При проверке выполнено 19 из 24 тестов, или 15 и 24. Увы условия тестов мне не доступны. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как ещё можно улучшить код? 
Может использовать BufferedReader()?

Во мой код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;       

class Series{ 
  static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);       

  public static void main (String[] args){ 
  int x = in.nextInt(), a = in.nextInt(), i=0;  
  long c=0;            

  if(a>=0){ 
    while(i!=a){ 
    c+=x; 
    i++;} 
  }else{ 
    while(i!=x&i!=-x){ //при замене "x" на "a" , 
    c+=a;              //"a" на "x" тесты показывают 15 из 24 
    i++;} 
  }       

System.out.println(c);  
 } 
}
```

Comment: ваша программа выдает неверный результат, если оба числа отрицательны, возможно проблема в этом. Вообще, сделайте простой тест, переберите в цикле все пары множителей от -10 до 10, и сравните результат вашего кода с результатом умножения.

Comment: Вынужден не согласиться с вами. Проверял ранее и сейчас проверяю, всё работает. И с минусами и без и с нулями.

Comment: Вероятно я не учёл, что при умножении "-" на "-" получается "+".  Извиняюсь за не точность.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static long multiply(long a, long b)
    {
        if (a == 0 || b == 0)
            return 0;

        boolean negative = false;
        if (a < 0) {
            negative = true;
            a = -a;
        }
        if (b < 0) {
            negative = !negative;
            b = -b;
        }

        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= a; ++i)
            result += b;

        return negative ? -result : result;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final long a = scanner.nextInt();
        final long b = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println(multiply(a, b));
    }
}
```

Comment: а ограничения в задачи какие были? Если `10^9` то может не успеть...

Comment: Спасибо, классное решение. Тест прошёл.